# Does having the same keyword for two different countries count as keyword cannibalization and consequently affect ranking on Google?

Tags: seo, keywords, geotargeting

I've got a website that sells different kinds of industrial belts. It features a collection of products we sell and information about those products. Our website doesn't have a store and the primary way of getting hold of a product is via phone and the second way is filling the requirement forms laid out at different places throughout the website.

Originally, our website was optimized for gaining traffic from country A. Now, I want to expand our reach to surrounding countries B, C, and D. While the content will change a bit, most of it will remain the same, including the products we sell while focusing on SEO for these countries.

Let's say one of the landing pages targeting country A has the title **"Industrial Belts in Country A."**

Now, I want the same product to be served for country B. Will it be okay if I set the title to be **"Industrial Belts in Country B"** or will it cause a keyword cannibalization problem?

If yes, then what is the alternate course of option?

It's worth noting that while the target country changes, the language is supposed to remain the same.

Comment: How are you targeting different parts of your site to different countries?   Are you using different country code domain names?  Are you using subdomains of your main domain and setting targeting options in Google Search Console?    Are you using `hreflang`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller although I've considered using these options (using hreflang, using subdomains), much of the content will remain the same. So, I figure a simple landing page for each country should do the trick. I'm going to use the most-selling product from our portfolio for that particular country in the title.

Comment: You still need `hreflang` if the content is the same. It _is_ designed for what you want to do. Just use the sub-page method.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. You are targeting extremely niche, long-tail keywords. It is typical in the industry to target modifier + location keywords.

For example, a real estate company may have several pages targeting real estate + location.

If it is a product page Google (or other search engines) understands that there is going to be somewhat of a template in place.

I would still recommend adding unique content based on location to each page.

Also, if you are going to be targeting other countries (just as some of the feed mentions) using a folder structure for other countries, translate pages in the local language, utilize hreflang tags, and proper the canonicals.

This would completely ensure that you do not deal with keyword cannibalism as well as provide a positive user experience for users who speak native the language of that country. You can set the original language as the default.